# Subsetting dataframe based on underscore at the end of an element's name

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I am working with a data frame where the same elements occur more than once. In that case, the original occurrence is shown as element_1 in the first column, and all recurring elements are shown as element_2, element_3, etc.
Here's what it looks like:

```
Bear<-c("X03419","X10875_1","X10875_2","X12553","X32463_1","X32463_2","X32463_3")
Year<-c(2007,2008,2018,2005,2007,2005,2008)
Data<-data.frame(Bear,Year)
Data

Bear     Year
X03419   2007
X10875_1 2008
X10875_2 2018
X12553   2005
X32463_1 2007
X32463_2 2005
X32463_3 2008
```

I want to take out all rows with recurring elements but keep all the other ones (so, the only thing left should be elements without underscores or element_1 - type elements).

Would anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

We could use `grepl` to get the subset the rows.  Match the pattern in 'Bear' column by checking if there are one or more digits (`\\d+`) that succeed a `_` at the end (`$`) of the string and negate (`!`) to return the rows without those cases

```
subset(Data, !grepl('_\\d+$', Bear))
#    Bear Year
#1 X03419 2007
#4 X12553 2005
```

Or if the intention is to remove only the `_1`

```
subset(Data, !grepl('_1$', Bear))
#      Bear Year
#1   X03419 2007
#3 X10875_2 2018
#4   X12553 2005
#6 X32463_2 2005
#7 X32463_3 2008
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Could you tell me what the "\\d+" means in your first answer?

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr`, we can filter based on the condition that "_" is included:

```
Bear<-c("X03419","X10875_1","X10875_2","X12553","X32463_1","X32463_2","X32463_3")
Year<-c(2007,2008,2018,2005,2007,2005,2008)
Data<-data.frame(Bear,Year)

library(dplyr)

Data = Data %>% 
  dplyr::filter(!grepl('_', Bear))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can do

```
filter_at(Data, vars(Bear), ~ !grepl("_(?:1)", Bear))
#       Bear Year
# 1   X03419 2007
# 2 X10875_2 2018
# 3   X12553 2005
# 4 X32463_2 2005
# 5 X32463_3 2008
```

- `_(?:1)`: not match string containing `_1`